# Show Files in CFolderPickerDialog C++

Tags: c++, mfc

When utilizing `CFolderPickerDialog` in a MFC application, is there any way I can view the files as well. I understand that there are way cool options to select a folder, but I need to make sure the files I want are in that directory as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `CFolderPickerdialog` not allowing users to see the files within the dialog box came as a WYSIWYG moment. SO your option then becomes to utilize the `CFileDialog` and then trim the `path` to `Folderpath` as described in the code below.

```
 CFileDialog dlg (OFNHIDERADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT | BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES, NULL);

...

CString path = dlg.GetPathName();

CString Folderpath = path.Left(path.ReverseFind('\\'));

if (Folderpath.Right(1) != "\\")
    Folderpath +=  "\\";
```

Therefore, your code may look like `C:\Users\foldername\file.txt`
but will now look like this `C:\Users\foldername\`

Comment: This does not appear to be a proper solution. Requesting the user to pick a folder, and then have them select a **file** inside the folder is pretty counter-intuitive. A solution would be to use [IFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775966.aspx) with the `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` [FILEOPENDIALOGOPTIONS enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn457282.aspx) value.

Comment: Either way, the code you posted as a solution doesn't even compile. There is no `OFNHIDERADONLY`, and mixing the `OPENFILENAME` *Flags* with *ulFlags* from the [BROWSEINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773205.aspx) structure isn't going to end well either. There is also no `CFileDialog` c'tor taking the argument types you propose.

Comment: What's the reason for mixing unrelated flags? I cannot think of a single valid reason to do so. Generally, answers on SO should not be of the type *"you can work out the rest"*. Answers are supposed to be complete. As posted, it is not useful, and I'm afraid I'll have to vote accordingly.